# Collision with multiple elements (each function?)

Tags: javascript, jquery, collision-detection

i have a div (`"#basket"`) which should catch many elements with the same class (`".food"`)

```
function collision($div1, $div2) {
      var x1 = $div1.offset().left;
      var y1 = $div1.offset().top;
      var h1 = $div1.outerHeight(true);
      var w1 = $div1.outerWidth(true);
      var b1 = y1 + h1;
      var r1 = x1 + w1;
      var x2 = $div2.offset().left;
      var y2 = $div2.offset().top;
      var h2 = $div2.outerHeight(true);
      var w2 = $div2.outerWidth(true);
      var b2 = y2 + h2;
      var r2 = x2 + w2;
      if (b1 < y2 || y1 > b2 || r1 < x2 || x1 > r2) return false;

      var value = Number(($div1).attr("data-value"));
      $("#counter").html(parseInt($("#counter").html()) + value);

      function getsmall() {
        $div1.remove();
        //$div1.stop().animate({width: "0px",height:"0px"}, 200, function(){});
      }
      getsmall();
}


   window.setInterval(function() {
        var basket = $('#basket');
        var food_1 = ('#food_1'); // classname .food
        var food_2 = ('#food_2'); // classname .food
        collision($(food_1), $(basket));
        collision($(food_2), $(basket));
    }, 200);
```

there will be more than 20 of the .food and i dont want to write that many of code if i'm using `ids` of each element.

the function works great with two unique elements (two ids), but not with one element with an id and more than 20 elements with only classnames.

how can the function `collision` be executed to the `#basket` and many elements with classname `.food` ?

Comment: Nope, no idea what your asking. Can you clarify your question, it's not clear at all

Comment: edited the question

Comment: You might want to use a graphing library like d3.js instead, for which implementation of collision is quite straight forward and trivial.

Comment: What exactly are you stuck on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `each` function, it loops through all the elements in the jQuery object:

```
window.setInterval(function(){
    var basket = $('#basket');
    var food = $('.food');
    // Here comes the magic
    food.each(function(){
        collision($(this), $(basket));
    });
}, 200);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foods=document.getElementsByClass("food");
foods.forEach(function(food){
    collision(basket,food);
 });
```

the firstline stores an collection of elements (like an array) that have the class food inside of the variable foods. Now you can loop trough (forEach) and call your collision function for each basket food combination.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByClassName ... HTMLCollection...

Comment: turns out the docs describe it as an [*"array-like object"*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) which is news to me. Turns out I'm wrong...